# VBA Strings without Dollar Signs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning about VBA, and I've noticed an odd quirk when VBA interacts with adding strings. When you take the two versions of code (Change the commented parts with the swap here commented parts) one outputs a string with a dollar sign, and one does without. Does anybody know if this is a bug or is planned to be upgraded?

```
Option Explicit
Sub CalcCost()
Dim curSalesPrice As Currency
Dim curTotalCost As Currency
Dim sngSalesTax As Single
Dim strMessage As String

 curSalesPrice = 35
 sngSalesTax = 0.085

    Range("A1:B8").ClearContents
    Range("A1").Value = "The cost of the calculator"
    Range("A4").Value = "Price"
    Range("B4").Value = curSalesPrice
    Range("A5").Value = "SalesTax"
    Range("A6").Value = "Cost"
    Range("B5").Value = curSalesPrice * sngSalesTax

    'curTotalCost = curSalesPrice + (curSalesPrice * sngSalesTax)
    curTotalCost = Format(curSalesPrice + (curSalesPrice * sngSalesTax), "Currency") 'swap here


    'strMessage = "The calculator total is " & Format(curTotalCost, "Currency")
    strMessage = "The calculator total is " & curTotalCost 'swap here

    Range("A8").Value = strMessage
    Range("B6").Value = curTotalCost

End Sub
```

Comment: In one instance you are using the Format method to format it as Currency and the other you are not. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: Why would that be a bug? What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 3):

`Format` is a VBA standard library function defined in the `VBA.Strings` module; it returns a `String` *representation* of the expression it's given, formatted as specified: it makes no sense to do this:

```
Dim foo As Currency ' a numeric data type...
foo = Format(123, "Currency") ' ...assigned to a string representation of a numeric value
```

But it makes complete sense here:

```
Dim msg As String
msg = Format(123, "Currency")
```

Now, the *value* of a cell is distinct from its *text representation*. It's not because you see `$123.00` in a cell that the *value* of that cell is `$123.00` (a `String`); that's the cell's `Text`, but its `Value` can very well be `123` (a `Double`) and its `NumberFormat` be `$#0.00`.

You want to use numeric data types to perform operations, and use `Format` only when you need to make these numeric values "pretty" for display. Avoid making arithmetic operations on strings: while that *may* work, it also *may* fail, depending on how the string is formatted, and the system locale: VBA needs to make implicit type conversions to carry out such operations, and implicit conversions need to make a number of (sometimes wrong) assumptions.

When writing numeric values to worksheet cells, write the numeric values, not a string representation of them (same for dates. *especially* dates, actually). Instead of `Format`-ing the values, specify a format string for `Range.NumberFormat` in the cells that need to be formatted. That way Excel will still understand the numeric values as such, and can still correctly perform e.g. SUM operations.

The code is working exactly as specified and intended.